# Java: Add to array by JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, joptionpane

I have this array:

```
String[] countriesList = {
                "Japan",
                "Sverige",
                "Tyskland",
                "Spanien",
                "Syrien",
                "Litauen",                                      
};
```

I want to be able to add another thing to the array, in this case this [6]th position. Is it possible to do this by JOPtionPane? This is what I've done this far, however nothing happens nor does any errors occur.

```
String addland = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vilket land vill du lägga till?").trim();
            countriesList[6] = addland;
```

Comment: Try to use an ArrayList.

Comment: Arrays have fixed size. Use resizeable collection like List, or create array with bigger size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays` start their counting from 0, so you could use `countriesList[5] = addland;`

You may use a `dynamic list` to perform your task.
They are better in every situation and should be superior to simple `Arrays`

Try to use this

```
List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<>(
Arrays.asList("Japan", "Sverige", "Tyskland", "Spanien", "Syrien", "Litauen"));

String addland = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vilket land vill du lägga till?").trim();
countriesList.set(5,addland);
System.out.println(countriesList);
```

Output, after entering `asdadsad`:

```
[Japan, Sverige, Tyskland, Spanien, Syrien, asdadsad]
```

To add a land to the existing list use `countriesList.add(addland);` instead of `countriesList.set(5,addland);`

Comment: I get The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
 ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Maybe you importet the wrong List. Make sure your imports are `java.util.ArrayList` , 
`java.util.Arrays` and 
`java.util.List`, also dont use 6 as a set variable because array counting starts at 0 so 5 is your last entry

Comment: So I still can't add another String to the List? That was my question all along. I want to create [6].

Comment: You can add as much items as you want to the `array list` (in fact only 2,147,483,647 items because thats the limit of int). Thats the good part about it. Just use the `add` method on an `array list` object. Use this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to learn more about `Array Lists`. My comment was on the `set` method which requires an existing element to replace -> `set(5,yourstring)` means that the `String` on position 5 gets replaced with the second argument.